# MySQL stripping off leading zero from integer column

Tags: mysql

I have a `bigint` field which when entering a number such as `'05555555555'` for example, the 0 is being stripped off and only inserting `'5555555555'`.

What data type should I use to prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Integer columns (bigint's) do not store leading zeros (ie. in a visual representation)

Rather than attempt to store a leading zero (by using a varchar field), have a view (or whatever) format the integer into a string in the format you require.

If you need to store something that is actually a string in the Domain model (e.g. a phone number), use a string rather than an integer type field.

Comment: Weird that this was downvoted, but Andrew Moore's answer was upvoted twice when they say the same thing.

Comment: @Andrew - ZEROFILL does exactly that in a visual manner. It even combo's with PHP to present the end result zero filled. Check OP's other questions.

Answer (score 3):

`BIGINT` and other **Integer** columns do not store the visual representation of a number, only the number itself in binary form (`BIGINT` is 8 bytes). 5555555555 is stored as:

> `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 01001011 00100011 00001100 11100011`

If the preceding zeros are significant to the integrity of your data, you should be using a `VARCHAR` or `CHAR` instead of an integer type. Numerical datatypes should only be used for numerical data. US ZIP Codes and phone numbers are NOT numerical data.

Answer (score 2):

`bigint` stores the data as a number, and `05555555555` and `5555555555` are the same number. You'll need a string type to preserve the leading zero, e.g. `varchar` with a suitable maximum length.

Answer (score -3):

Problem is if you got a big database with hundredthousands of rows, a bigint, is much faster then a VARHAR field. I got a similar issue with a product database full with European Article Numbers(EAN).Some of those codes start with a leading 0 When i change it to VARCHAR it takes 8 seconds to load certain pages that search for EAN codes, when I change it to BIGINT it turns into 2 seconds. 
Big difference in speed indeed.