# inserting mobile number in database in ci using jquery ajax function

Tags: jquery, html, codeigniter

i want to insert 11 digits in database usingh ajax funciton in ci
when i give the value 03337276335 it insert 3337276335.
why it trim 0 from (0337276335).
my table data type is bigint 255.
here is my html

```
<input id="mobile"  type="text" class="form-control in_sub" placeholder="Enter Your Mobile Number"  />
 <button class="btn btn-primary subs">Subscribe</button>
```

here is my ajax funciton

```
$('.subs').click(function(){
            mobile = $('#mobile').val()
            if (mobile!='') {
                if ($.isNumeric(mobile)) { 
                    if (mobile.length == 11) {
                                $.ajax({
                            url: '<?php echo site_url('home/mobileupdate'); ?>',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: {
                                mobile:mobile
                            },
                            success:function(data){
                                $('#update_mobile').text(data).css('color','green');
                            },
                            error:function(){
                                $('#update_mobile').text('Some thing wrong..').css('color','red');
                            }
                        });
                    } 
                    else{

                    $('#update_mobile').text('Example: 0123123456');

                    };

                }
                 else{
                    $('#update_mobile').text('insert a Numbric value: 0333');

                };
            } 
            else{
                $('#update_mobile').text('Please Insert a mobile number..');
            };

        });
```

here is my controller

```
public function mobileupdate(){
        $data['mobile'] = $this->input->post('mobile');
        $query = $this->mod_home->mobileupdate($data);

        if ($query) {
            echo 'Thanx for subscribe.';
        } else {
            echo 'error in network please send a feedback.';
        }

    }
```

here is my model

```
public function mobileupdate($data){
                $data['mobile'];
            return $this->db->insert('mobileupdate',$data);
        }
```

Comment: you save an integer, so you always loose your leading `0`, try to save a telephone-number as varchar. have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4835063/4202224)

Comment: you can too try mysql data type `varchar` if this fits to your requirement...